# BIDS Package Error's on Truncate while EXPORTING to flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bids

I have a BIDS package. The final "Data Flow Task" exports a SQL table to Flat File. I receive a truncation error on this process. What would cause a truncation error while exporting to flat file? The error was occurring within the "OLE DB" element under the Data Flow tab for the "Data Flow Task".

I have set the column to ignore truncation errors and the export works fine.

I understand truncation errors. I understand why they would happen when you are importing data into a table. I do not understand why this would happen when outputting to a flat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be occurring for many reasons. Please make sure some of the steps listed below:

1) Check the source Data types that has to match with destination data type. If there are different it might through Truncation Error.

2) Check if there are blocks :- You can check this by creating Data viewer before the Destination and see the data come through.

Comment: In step 1 you are referring to the mapping correct?

Comment: Step 1) Not only mapping column but also mapping datatype for eg: Int in source to Int in destination or varchar(25) in source to varchar(25) in destination

Comment: 2) Very useful. Is there a way to go through a couple million records more efficiently?

Comment: I personally suggest you to create a temporary table exactly same like destination and do it in 2 steps - 1) Dump the flat file record to temp table and 2) simple grab records from temp to destination.