# Package Validation Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, business-intelligence, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm trying to use a foreach loop container to import several excel files into a table, I specified the folder and the files I'm going to use (*.xls), after that I created a path variable then I went to the excel source connection and in the "Expression" property I selected the variable. I created the foreach container but, the excel source's connectionString only shows `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`, so it means it's not taking the variable value. What can I do to solve that?

**Note:** I'm using SQL Server 2012

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

```
Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [20]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

Error at Package [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
```

Comment: Set `DelayValidation` to `True` and try again

Comment: Also change the `ConnectionString` Expression to use `ExcelFilePath` instead using your Path variable.

Comment: There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. Navigate back to log. It will exactly tell what happened.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made a combination among your comments and Maverick's Answer and it worked fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the link below where I answer mainly focus on `RUN64BITS` TO `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

[Execel Source ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261054/error-debugging-ssis-excel-source-data-conversion-ole-db-destination/22261164#22261164)

Comment: Again this may not be the case always but for me the excel was corrupted.

I followed these steps after wasting 3 hours:

tried to open the source excel file, it didn't open and prompted the file is corrupted.
recreated the excel file from the source, saved as excel (.xlsx) file
recreated the connection manager and edited excel source
and everything works fine.

Comment: After I read this comment, i double checked my excel file, surprisingly although i had created the file myself, it was showing a message saying this file is locked for editing for a different user, so recreated it with a different name and updated my Excel connection manager and it worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Running a SQL 2012 SSIS Package via an MVC Website fails with:

> The Script Task is corrupted.

and

> There were errors during task validation.

Runs perfectly from with in BIDS.

---

To resolve it I set the Project Property:

```
Run64BitRunTime = False  
Security = DontSaveSensitive
```

In the Package I set:

```
DelayValidation = True
Security = DontSaveSensitive
```

This still failed. I came across [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/317) which indicates that  Script Tasks are the problem.

So I removed the script task and it worked straight away.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? It might not be a solution but it's the root cause.